# Obter a data e a hora que o computador ligou

Tags: c#

Gostaria de um método para obter a data e a hora que o computador ligou pela ultima vez com o (c# windows form application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o ManagementObjectSearcher.

```
    using System.Management;
    using System.Linq;

    public static DateTime GetLastBootUpTime() 
    {
        DateTime lastBootUpTime = new DateTime();

        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Primary='true'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            lastBootUpTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo.Properties["LastBootUpTime"].Value.ToString());

        }

        return lastBootUpTime;
    }
```

> É necessário referênciar a dll System.Management ao projeto.

Outra alternativa é utilizando o TickCount:

```
    private static DateTime GetLastBootUpTimeByTickCount()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime boot = now - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount);

        return boot;
    }
```

> Nota: O problema é que essa outra alternativa com TickCount irá
>   funcionar por somente 25 dias devido ao TickCount ser do tipo Int32.

Answer (score 3):

Pode consultar o [*performance counter* que indica à quanto tempo o sistema esta activo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms725496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (isto é, quanto tempo passou desde a ultima vez que o *Windows* iniciou e subtrair esse tempo à data actual:

```
using (var counterTempoActivo = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
{
    counterTempoActivo.NextValue();
    TimeSpan tempoActivo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(counterTempoActivo.NextValue());
    return DateTime.Now.Subtract(tempoActivo);
}
```

**Extra**:

Caso precise de garantir a localização correcta das *strings* pode fazê-lo usando a função [PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa372648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
// Importe a função
[DllImport("pdh.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern UInt32 PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex(string szMachineName, uint dwNameIndex, StringBuilder szNameBuffer, ref uint pcchNameBufferSize); 

// Este método usa a função importada e procura a *string* associada ao ID passado
public string ProcurarStringLocalizada(uint id)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
    uint bufSize = (uint)buffer.Capacity;
    PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex(null, id, buffer, ref bufSize);
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Neste caso, o ID para a *string* "System" é 2, e para a *string* "System Up Time" é 674. Estes IDs podem ser encontrados no seguinte chave do registo do *Windows*:

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\CurrentLanguage\Counter".

Por fim, o método original ficaria:

```
const uint systemId = 2;
const uint upTimeId = 674;
string categoria = ProcurarStringLocalizada(systemId);
string counter = ProcurarStringLocalizada(upTimeId);

using (var counterTempoActivo = new PerformanceCounter(categoria, counter))
{
    counterTempoActivo.NextValue();
    TimeSpan tempoActivo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(counterTempoActivo.NextValue());
    return DateTime.Now.Subtract(tempoActivo);
}
```

Comment: Isso funciona mesmo se o usuário modificar a data atual?

Comment: Nesse caso o problema vai ser a chamada do `Datetime.Now` que lê o relógio do sistema.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar relativemente ao *counter* não encontrei fontes, mas estive a testar numa VM e alterar o relógio **não** altera o *counter*

Comment: Saquei, mas eu tava falando mais pelo `DateTime.Now` mesmo...

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu computador nunca passe mais de 49.7 dias ligado:

- Obtenha o número de milisegundos passados desde o boot até o momento atual;
- Subtraia este número da data atual.

Este código pode ser expresso em uma linha:

```
var bootTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(
                   TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
                       System.Environment.TickCount));
```

Fontes:

[GetTickCount function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx), MSDN
[How to know when was Windows started or shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407286/how-to-know-when-was-windows-started-or-shutdown), StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Li alguns [exemplos](http://michal.is/blog/query-the-event-log-with-c-net/) onde você pode usar as classes do *namespace* **[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader(VS.90).aspx)** para acessar os logs do *Event Viewer* e obter essa informação.

Apesar de não possuir um ambiente para tentar realizar um teste local acredito que seria interessante dar uma olhada nessas referências.

Você usa a classe *[EventLogQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery(v=vs.90).aspx)* para criar a consulta desejada no *Event Viewer* e executa a leitura dos dados usando a classe *[EventLogReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader(v=vs.90).aspx)*.

Abaixo um código de exemplo:

```
EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(Level = 3)]]");
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query);
EventRecord eventRecord;
while ((eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}",
        eventRecord.TimeCreated,
        eventRecord.FormatDescription()));
}
```